# Selecting multiple column of Tableview

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstableview

There is a requirement, where user needs to select multiple column in the Tableview. 
But only one column can be selected at a time. Multiple column can be selected by using Shift key but it select consecutive columns.

Suppose I have a requirement where I need to select Column 1 & Column 3 simultaneously to get highlighted. What needs to be done? Is there any XIB setting to do so or any delegate methods for the same?

Thanks.

Comment: Column in table view? Did you mean to say rows of tableView ?

Comment: Command-click doesn't work but NSTableView does support discontinuous selection of multiple columns. Did you try `tableView:didClickTableColumn:` and `selectColumnIndexes:byExtendingSelection:`?